# How do you create an add/push function in a XOR linked list (C++)?

Tags: c++, linked-list, xor

I am creating a XOR linked list for practice in C++, but I can't get the add function to work. It seems that every time I add an element, it moves the head pointer to that element and I lose the previous one. Can't seem to debug this.

Heres my code.

```
class XORLinkedList {
public:
    XORLinkedList() : head(nullptr), tail(nullptr) {}
/*  XORLinkedList(int data){
        xNode* temp = new xNode(data);
        head = tail = temp;
    }*/
    void add(int data){                                  //Doesn't seem to work 
        xNode* temp = new xNode(data);
        if(head == nullptr){
            //cout <<"first added: " << temp->getData() << endl;
            head = tail = temp;
            temp->assignNpx(nullptr);
            cout << "1head is now: " << head->getData() << endl;
        } else {
            if(tail->getNpx() == nullptr){  //there is only one node
                tail->assignNpx(XOR(nullptr, temp));
                //cout <<"nested if: added: " << temp->getData() << endl;
                cout << "2head is now: " << head->getData() << endl;
            } else {
                //cout <<"nested else: added: " << temp->getData() << endl;
                xNode *prev = XOR(tail->getNpx(), nullptr);
                tail->assignNpx(XOR(prev, temp));
                cout << "3head is now: " << head->getData() << endl;
            }
            temp->assignNpx(XOR(tail, nullptr));
            tail = temp;
            cout << "4head is now: " << head->getData() << endl;
        }
        cout << "head is now: " << head->getData() << endl;
        cout << "tail is now: " << tail->getData() << endl;
        delete temp;
    }
    xNode* XOR(xNode* a, xNode* b){
        return (xNode*)((uintptr_t)(a) ^ (uintptr_t)(b));
    }
private:
    xNode* head;
    xNode* tail;
};

class xNode {
public:
    xNode(int _val = 0) : val(_val) {}
    xNode* getNpx() { return npx; }
    void assignNpx(xNode* ptr){
        npx = ptr;
    }
    int getData(){ return val; }
private:
    int val;
    xNode* npx;
};
```

Comment: You appear to be deleting the new node at the end of `add`? I feel like the logic is overcomplicated anyway, but that `delete` looks like instant breakage.

Comment: Thank you, I think that worked. It has been a while since I wrote C++. I thought you were supposed to free pointers up with the delete function, but i think I was deleting the node itself. I guess the pointer gets deleted when it goes out of scope.